# How to write MongoDBs aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and node js and I am trying to match value from table I have two tables join.

```
private async FunDCT_GetPermissionCount(cSearchFilterQuery) {
    const oCount = await Permission.aggregate([
    cSearchFilterQuery,
    {
        $lookup: {
        from: "gen_accesstypes",
        localField: "iAccessTypeID",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "oAccessTypeListing"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$oAccessTypeListing" },
    ], function (err, documents) {
    if (err) { return false; }
    return documents;
    });

    return oCount.length;
```

I have to match value from `oAccessTypeListing`. `oAccessTypeListing` has `cAccessName` column and I have to match that but I don't know query if someone know help me.

My query that does not work:

```
cSearchFilterQuery = { $match: { $or: [{ "cAccessName": { "$regex": 'filter string', "$options": "i" } }] } };
```

`oCount` returns object:

```
[
    
            {
                "_id": "6107a244f5399e480c97371e",
                "cAdd": "N",
                "cEdit": "N",
                "cView": "Y",
                "cDelete": "N",
                "iAccessTypeID": "5fc50acbd4e25f2318c4196c",
                "iProcessID": "5ff81e4eeb2477320447cd3f",
                "iStatusID": "5fc4f96dd4e25f2318c4194e",
                "iEnteredby": "5fc50ad530bb6544245885ff",
                "tEntered": "2021-08-02T07:44:04.868Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "oPermissionListing": {
                    "_id": "5fc4f96dd4e25f2318c4194e",
                    "cStatusCode": "ACTIVE",
                    "cStatusName": "Active",
                    "cStatusDesc": "Active Records"
                },
                "oAccessTypeListing": {
                    "_id": "5fc50acbd4e25f2318c4196c",
                    "cAccessCode": "Member",
                    "cAccessName": "Member",
                    "cAccessDesc": "Member User",
                    "iStatusID": "5fc4f96dd4e25f2318c4194e",
                    "iUpdatedby": "5fc50ad530bb6544245885ff",
                    "tUpdated": "2020-11-30T17:26:58.707Z",
                    "iEnteredby": "5fc50ad530bb6544245885ff",
                    "tEntered": "2020-12-30T06:13:08.589Z"
                },
                "oProcessListing": {
                    "_id": "5ff81e4eeb2477320447cd3f",
                    "cProcessCode": "LIST_TEMPLATE",
                    "cProcessName": "LIST Template",
                    "cProcessDesc": "LIST Template",
                    "iStatusID": "5fc4f96dd4e25f2318c4194e"
                },
                "oUserListing": {
                    "_id": "5fc50ad530bb6544245885ff",
                    "iAccessTypeID": "5fc50ab9d4e25f2318c4196a",
                    "cEmail": "mpatil@shipco.com",
                    "cPassword": "$2a$10$ti5Zsy7uwIlP7MPlvW1DkuNNR4ynpotWbTRWqsevPiGPbkK0OzeCu",
                    "cAvatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea2e738c91b6c65f1d88cf5cf1d4ead1?s=200&r=pg&d=mm",
                    "cName": "Mayur Patil",
                    "cUsername": "mpatil",
                    "cCompanyname": "ALLINK",
                    "cAddress": "PNQ",
                    "cCity": "PNQ City",
                    "cPostalcode": "PNQ Postalcode",
                    "cState": "PNQ State",
                    "cPhone": "PNQ Phone",
                    "cFax": "PNQ FAX",
                    "iStatusID": "5fc4f96dd4e25f2318c4194e",
                    "tEntered": "2020-11-30T15:08:05.024Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "cPwdToken": "958402",
                    "iUpdatedby": "5fc50ad530bb6544245885ff",
                    "tUpdated": "2021-05-27T12:59:54.389Z"
                }
            }
 ]
```

Comment: Please share data of two table, what data you want in result

Comment: cSearchFilterQuery condition put after unwind

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar i added oCount object and i done "cSearchFilterQuery condition put after unwind" but that not works

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar i have to match value from `oAccessTypeListing`. that has `cAccessName`.

Comment: oAccessTypeListing.cAccessName   use

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar ya thats works thank you so much for helping me.